# Why '\0'.ToString()==string.Empty returns FALSE?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I just cannot get the point: If '\0' is an empty char and if a string is a kind of array of chars why this happens?

```
char value = '\0';
bool isEmpty = value.ToString() == string.Empty; // This returns FALSE because 
                                                 // '\0'.ToString() returns "\0" 
                                                 // where I expect it to be 
                                                 // string.empty
```

Comment: Its not empty because it contains a null character. The "null terminated string" semantic does not apply here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure chars cannot be empty

Comment: Your title is about a string, the text about a char... They are different.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no such thing as an "empty char", so your assumption in the first sentence is incorrect. A string with a single character (U+0000) is not the same as an empty string - for a start, the length of the first string is 1, not 0.

Calling `ToString()` on a `char` will *always* return a string of length 1, containing just that character. That's the only thing that it makes sense to do, IMO. I don't know why you would *expect* anything else.

While U+0000 is often used as a terminating character, it's not the same as the character "not existing". The string "Foo\0Bar" is *not* the same as "FooBar", and shouldn't be treated the same.

In short: it's your expectations which are incorrect, not .NET :)

Answer (score 3):

Because of `"\0".Length == 1`...

Answer (score 2):

I would personally call that a null character rather than an empty character. Whatever it is though its a character and a string which has a character in is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

In C, that would be an empty string.  In C#, this code creates a string containing one character, the NULL character.  The length of this string is therefore 1, and it does not equal the empty string.

Comment: Note that this being an empty string in C is only a *convention*. We all get together and agree that we will interpret a pointer to a zero char as a string of zero length. We don't *have* to all agree to that convention, and there are C programs that do not use that convention. The BSTR data structure that OLE Automation programs use, for example, does not follow this convention.

Answer (score 0):

.NET does not use null-terminated strings.  It uses the managed String class, which has completely different semantics.  C and C++ used null terminators because their notion of a "string" variable was actually just a pointer to the beginning of a character array, and the null terminator was a convenient way to scan for the end of the string.  In .NET, since the String is a full-fledged managed class, this mechanism is unnecessary.

Comment: Though note that *as an implementation detail*, all .NET strings are in fact ended with a zero char in their block of memory. That's so that for interop scenarios, the runtime engine developers can easily pass string pointers to C-style string manipulation methods without having to worry about making a copy to a null-terminated buffer.

Comment: That is an excellent point.  I was speaking only to what's necessary from the perspective of a managed language.  The scenario you mention does bring up a further issue of interoperability issues - if someone embeds a null char into a C# string, then passes it to an API function, for instance, the API string will end at the first null char, potentially causing unexpected results.  I'm sure you're aware of this; I'm only including it for the sake of completeness :)